# gcc nested libraries and linker dependencies

Tags: linker, dependencies, nested

Situation:

- i have a static library "lib1.a" ;
- a second static library "lib2.a" that uses the functions of "lib1.a";
- an application that directly uses just the functions of "lib2.a".

When i link the application i have to pass to the application dependencies also "lib1.a" even if the application do not calls directly none of lib1 functions. Lib2 is a sort of more high level wrapper library.

Is there a way to link lib1 inside lib2 (a sort of intermediate linking) so that the "app" does not even know about the existence of lib1?

I know that i can scompact lib1.a and include the objects files inside lib2.a but is there another way so that is done automatically and JUST the USED object files are included inside lib2? Linke when you link the final app.

{app} -uses-> {lib2} -uses-> {[lib1]}

Cheers,
Davide

Answer (score 1):

> is there another way

No, there is not (on any UNIX-like system I know of).

The best you can do, when using GNU-`ld` or `gold`, is to write a `libcombined.a` as a linker script, containing `-l2 -l1`, and point the application to it.